# Search directory for files matching a certain size - Windows/PHP

Tags: php, search, command-line, filesize

Running a Windows Server 2003 system, with IIS6 and PHP.

I have a directory of images, approximately 20,000. I need to get a list of files matching a certain size of 9919 bytes. These are blank/generic images. I will use the list of the images to check with and image provider to see if an updated image is available.

Is there a way in Windows, PHP, or maybe some other command line utility I can install on the system to get a list of these files, without having to scan each file in the directory for the file size.

Answer (score 0):

The `DirectoryIterator` class will let you quickly iterate over your images, and the SPL `FileObject` it returns for each item will let you find the file size.

```
foreach (new DirectoryIterator('path/to/image/directory') as $item) {
     if ($item->isFile() && $item->getSize() == 9919) {
           // your code to handle each matching file here...
     }
}
```

[SplFileObject](http://php.net/manual/en/class.splfileobject.php)
[DirectoryIterator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.directoryiterator.php)